# Tomcat 7 crashes on startup when using JExcel Api in webapp

Tags: java, excel, tomcat

I'm trying to export data from a database into an Excelsheet using the [JExcel Api](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) when a specific servlet is called, but when starting Tomcat I get multiple exceptions. Here's the error message as given by eclipse:

```
Nov 01, 2012 10:57:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/web]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/web]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/write/WriteException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jxl.write.WriteException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
... 21 more

Nov 01, 2012 10:57:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more

Nov 01, 2012 10:57:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more
```

Here is the servlet code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import jxl.write.WriteException;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class Test
 */
@WebServlet(description = "A simple test.", urlPatterns = { "/test" })

public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Test() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            WriteExcel.writeTestFile();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Test!</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("I've written an Excel file!");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

And here is the code of the WriteExcel class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import jxl.CellView;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.format.UnderlineStyle;
import jxl.write.Formula;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.Number;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableFont;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

//tomcat hat probleme mit der jxl library
public class WriteExcel {

  private WritableCellFormat timesBoldUnderline;
  private WritableCellFormat times;
  private String inputFile;

public void setOutputFile(String inputFile) {
  this.inputFile = inputFile;
  }

  public void write() throws IOException, WriteException {
    File file = new File(inputFile);
    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

    wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
    workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
    WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    createLabel(excelSheet);
    createContent(excelSheet);

    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
  }

  private void createLabel(WritableSheet sheet)
      throws WriteException {
    // Lets create a times font
    WritableFont times10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10);
    // Define the cell format
    times = new WritableCellFormat(times10pt);
    // Lets automatically wrap the cells
    times.setWrap(true);

    // Create create a bold font with unterlines
    WritableFont times10ptBoldUnderline = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10, WritableFont.BOLD, false,
        UnderlineStyle.SINGLE);
    timesBoldUnderline = new WritableCellFormat(times10ptBoldUnderline);
    // Lets automatically wrap the cells
    timesBoldUnderline.setWrap(true);

    CellView cv = new CellView();
    cv.setFormat(times);
    cv.setFormat(timesBoldUnderline);
    cv.setAutosize(true);

    // Write a few headers
    addCaption(sheet, 0, 0, "Header 1");
    addCaption(sheet, 1, 0, "This is another header");


  }

  private void createContent(WritableSheet sheet) throws WriteException,
      RowsExceededException {
    // Write a few number
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      // First column
      addNumber(sheet, 0, i, i + 10);
      // Second column
      addNumber(sheet, 1, i, i * i);
    }
    // Lets calculate the sum of it
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    buf.append("SUM(A2:A10)");
    Formula f = new Formula(0, 10, buf.toString());
    sheet.addCell(f);
    buf = new StringBuffer();
    buf.append("SUM(B2:B10)");
    f = new Formula(1, 10, buf.toString());
    sheet.addCell(f);

    // Now a bit of text
    for (int i = 12; i < 20; i++) {
      // First column
      addLabel(sheet, 0, i, "Boring text " + i);
      // Second column
      addLabel(sheet, 1, i, "Another text");
    }
  }

  private void addCaption(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
      throws RowsExceededException, WriteException {
    Label label;
    label = new Label(column, row, s, timesBoldUnderline);
    sheet.addCell(label);
  }

  private void addNumber(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row,
      Integer integer) throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
    Number number;
    number = new Number(column, row, integer, times);
    sheet.addCell(number);
  }

  private void addLabel(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
      throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
    Label label;
    label = new Label(column, row, s, times);
    sheet.addCell(label);
  }


  public static void writeTestFile() throws WriteException, IOException {
    WriteExcel test = new WriteExcel();
    test.setOutputFile("d:/test.xls");
    test.write();
    System.out.println("Please check the result file under d:/test.xls");
  }

}
```

The method writeTestFile() from the WriteExcel class works fine when tested in a local standalone project.
The servlet itself also works when the method writeTestFile() is not called.
Could someone clarify why I'm getting the exceptions?
Also is there a fix or workaround?

Comment: The error is very clear: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/write/WriteException`. You need to add the relevant jars to your web application / tomcat.

Comment: Have u added jxl-xxxx.jar in your class path ?

Comment: The jar file is present in the project and in the /tomcatHome/lib  folder.
That's why this confuses me so much.

Comment: Try to open the jar "manually" and see whether you have jxl.write.WriteException class there. Maybe its a wrong jar.

Comment: Within the jar file exists a "WriteException.class" in the package "jxl.write".
And as I stated the class WriteExcel works fine when tested in a standalone project. So i don't think the jar file itself contains errors.

Comment: How do you start tomcat from eclipse? Do you use any plugin? Do you create a server in Servers view? Are you sure the eclipse is using the tomcat where you placed the jar? Do you have more that one tomcat?

Comment: I'm using tomcat via a server created in the serverview. When exporting the project to a .war file and deploying the project on tomcat directly the error still occurs, same error message in the console.
Eclipse takes the jar file into account, otherwise it would tell me that the class I'm using is missing.
Tomcat documentation states that all foreign jar files are to be placed into the /tomcatHome/lib folder. This definitly works with the sql jdbc drivers I'm using.

Comment: If you double click on the Server you have a section named "Server Locations" What do you have selected there? I would try with "Use Tomcat installation" and also look to make sure "Server path" points to right tomcat.

Comment: Try this: double click on the server, click on "Open launch configuration", go to Classpath tab and under User Entries add the jar.

Comment: @DanIliescu Adding the jar file to the class path of the server resolved the issue with the exceptions. Write that as an answer (as I want to give credit to you) and I will mark this question resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: double click on the server, click on "Open launch configuration", go to Classpath tab and under User Entries add the jar.